# unordered_map iterator points to end(), how can I retrieve a key from unordered_map?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stl

I am currently trying to return the key value *only* from an unordered_map, *groups*, that has a **string** as a **key** and a **vector of strings** as my **value**. I am currently encountering the issue that my ***it*** iterator for the unordered_map, *groups*, is pointing at the end() and makes my statement false, never returning my groupKey. I can only use hasNext and getNextHome to iterate through my map. So for-loops cannot be used for this task.
I've initialized them as such in my header file:

```
Home::Home()
{
    iter = 0;
    it = groups.begin();
}
```

```
private:
  int iter; // the iterator
  unordered_map<string, vector<string>>::iterator it; // iterator for the map
```

```
void Home::resetHomeIterator()
{
    iter = 0;
    it = groups.begin();
}
```

```
bool Home::hasNext() {
    if (iter == groups.size() && it == groups.end()) {              
        return false;
    }
    else if (iter < groups.size()) {
        return true; 
    }
    return false;
}
```

```
string Home::getNextHome()
{
    
    if (hasNext() == false || it == groups.end()) {
        resetHomeIterator();
    }
    it++;
    string groupKey = it->first;
    return groupKey;
}
```

Whenever I run this, the *it->first* gives me an error that I cannot "*dereference end list iterator*" and when I debug, I never get a groupKey back, it just goes to false so I never get a key returned.

I am trying to get a groupKey back and use a while-loop for my hasNext in my main.cpp file ( while (hasNext) ) and iterate the key values that way. I know my *group* map is not empty either, I saw as I was using the debugger that they were being placed accordingly. I've tried to work around it, but I'm not sure if I'm getting it. I might be missing something. How can I retrieve just the key since it's a string?

Comment: Iterators are for iterating and transient use. They often become invalidated when the underlying collection is modified, leading to undefined behaviour later. (From the part of your interface that you show, it looks like a vector of pairs would suit you better than a map.)

Comment: This is very confusing `int iter; // the iterator` It looks like you use `iter` for the size. It is not an iterator

Comment: @molbdnilo, In this case, I can't use anything else besides a map ): so I cannot use an unordered_map iterator to access the key right?

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for this question is because `iter` is out of bounds. The element number of  `groups` starts from `0`. `group.end()` points to the position after the last valid element in the continuous space. So, `iter` should not become `group.size()`.

```
if (iter == groups.size()-1 && it == groups.end()) {              
        return false;
    }
```

In addition, it is not recommended to use iterators in `Home`. Because `iterator` and `pointer` are not the same. Iterators are for iterating and should be considered transient, and not stored for later use.